How can I pass in a type that conforms to a protocol as an argument to a function?
Here's an example of what I am trying to achieve.
protocol PredicateBuilder {
    static func getpredicate(value: String)->NSCompoundPredicate?
}

class ExampleClass1: PredicateBuilder {
    static func getpredicate(value: String)->NSCompoundPredicate? {
        // ... create the predicate
        return predicate
    }
}

class ExampleClass2: PredicateBuilder {
    static func getpredicate(value: String)->NSCompoundPredicate? {
        //... create the predicate
        return predicate
    }

}

class CLAUSEPARSER {
    static func getPredicate(searchClause: String, predicateBuilder: BuilderClass) -> NSCompoundPredicate? {
        // ... parse the searchClause and build the compound predicate

        for word in searchClause {
            let predicate = predicateBuilder.getpredicate(value: word)
            // do stuff...
        }
    
        return theCompoundPredicate
    }
}

func main() {
    let predicate1 = CLAUSEPARSER.getPredicate(searchClause: searchString, predicateBuilder: ExampleClass1)

    let array1 = [ExampleClass1]()
    
    // ...fill the array
    
    let filteredArray1 = array1.filter({predicate1.evalute(with: $0)})
    
    let predicate2 = CLAUSEPARSER.getPredicate(searchClause: searchString, predicateBuilder: ExampleClass2)

    let array2 = [ExampleClass2]()

    // ...fill the array
    
    let filteredArray2 = array2.filter({predicate2.evalute(with: $0)})

}

What I am not clear on is how to define the predicateBuilder parameter in a function since it is a class that conforms to a protocol not an instance of the class.
EDIT:
I think I may have figured it out
static func getPredicate(searchClause: String, predicateBuilder: SearchPredicate.Type) -> NSCompoundPredicate?

and then when calling the function pass in the class Type.self
let predicate2 = CLAUSEPARSER.getPredicate(searchClause: searchString, predicateBuilder: ExampleClass2.self)


You should submit your edit as an answer.

@Alexander - Well it works but it that the correct way ?

Yep. And if it’s not, others will post their alternative answers

Don't use static functions in protocols. It should be forbidden on compiler level.

This question is similar to: How to define a `Class` object type conforming to a protocol?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you only have a single static function in the protocol then I think a viable option is to replace the whole protocol with a closure instead.
static func getPredicate(searchClause: String, 
                         predicateBuilder: (String) -> NSCompoundPredicate?) -> NSCompoundPredicate? {

This could make it easier to create common, reusable functions that different classes could use instead of implementing their own and it's one type less to handle.

I think this is probably the best suggestion given there is really just that single function required.  A protocol seemed a bit overkill.  Not sure why just using a closure didn't occur to me !

You can use generic to constraint type that you want to pass in have to conform to PredicateBuilder.
class CLAUSEPARSER {
    static func getPredicate<T: PredicateBuilder>(searchClause: String, predicateBuilder: T.Type) -> String? {
        // ... parse the searchClause and build the compound predicate

        for word in searchClause {
            let predicate = T.getpredicate(value: String(word))
            // do stuff...
        }
    
        return nil
    }
}

func main() {
    let predicate1 = CLAUSEPARSER.getPredicate(searchClause: "", predicateBuilder: ExampleClass1.self)

    let array1 = [ExampleClass1]()
    
    // ...fill the array
    
    let filteredArray1 = array1.filter({predicate1.evalute(with: $0)})
    
    let predicate2 = CLAUSEPARSER.getPredicate(searchClause: "", predicateBuilder: ExampleClass2.self)

    let array2 = [ExampleClass2]()

    // ...fill the array
    
    let filteredArray2 = array2.filter({predicate2.evalute(with: $0)})

}

